# How to iterate over ranges of a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iteration, c++14

I have a question on what's the best way to iterate over slices/ranges of a vector with C++11 or C++14. Let's say we have a `std::vector` that holds a bunch of values:

```
std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

This vector is used as input to calculate a value from `n` contiguous values, in operations similar to a moving average.  For this purpose, I have a function `foo` that takes `n` contiguous elements as input, does some math, and outputs a value.  This means this function looks something like the following declaration:

```
int foo(const std::vector<int> &v_range);
```

I want to apply `foo` to all elements of `v` to map them to another vector.
I could pull that off by iterating over the vector, extract a subvector, and pass it to `foo`.  See code below.

```cpp
// Example program
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int foo(const std::vector<int> &v) {
    
    std::cout << "[";
    for(int e: v) {
        std::cout << e << ",";
    }
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  std::vector<int> v_out;
  std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  std::vector<int> v_out;
  const int n = 3;

  for (auto begin = v.begin(), end = std::next(v.begin(), n);
       std::next(begin, n - 1) != v.end();
       ++begin, ++end) {
      std::vector<int> v_slice(begin, end);
      v_out.push_back(foo(v_slice));
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5Kcz7s48j)

The above works, but not only does it require a lot of boilerplate code but it also needlessly copy elements around.

I was wondering if C++ provided any clever way to easily iterate over slices/ranges of elements of a vector, which could be passed to either `std::transform` or `std::for_each`.

Alternatively, I was wondering if C++ offered any way to transform the input vector as a vector of vector ranges, similar to the following pseudocode:

```
  std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};


  std::vector<std::vector<int>> v_sliced = { 
    {0,1,2},
    {1,2,3},
    {2,3,4}
    ///...
    {8,9,10}
  };
```

Any input is welcomed.

Comment: Can you change `foo` to take range (C++20), iterators pair, `std::span` (C++20)?

Comment: @Jarod42 I apologize for not being clear, but this question is about C++11 or C++14. Meaning, stuff like [C++20's ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) doesn't apply.

Comment: `end++ != v.end()` - `v.end()++` is UB

Comment: There is still pair of iterators.(which would at least avoid the copy/creation of extra vector)

Comment: Don't spam language versions. If you ask about C++11 specifically, pick only C++11. If you ask about C++14 specifically, pick only C++14 only. If you limited with C++14, pick only C++14.

Comment: Why not use `int foo(std::vector<int>::iterator begin, std::vector<int>::iterator end);` and get rid of `v_slice`?

Comment: [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) support C++14.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for suggesting third-party libraries, but my question is focused on what's offered by standard C++.

Comment: @273K `foo` takes in a collection, and not a pair of iterators.

Comment: range-v3 is mostly code which was added in C++20 for ranges, so an easy drop replacement for later.

Comment: @Jarod42 it's hard to justify adding third-party dependencies to a project just to brush a loop under the rug, specially when the question is on whether standard C++ already covers this usecase.

Comment: Creating `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` would be even worse than creating one `std::vector` by loop iteration.

Comment: "foo takes in a collection, and not a pair of iterators" -- `foo` only needs to _read_ the elements of its input vector - there is no need to take a `const vector&`. In C++20 you would take a `std::span`, in C++14 you can take two iterators. Then you can just give your `begin` and `end` variables to `foo`

Comment: @Jarod42 if you're going to edit the example, please don't replace the existing example with broken code.

Comment: @chrysante `foo` is provided by a third-party library, and it's designed to take either a `std::vector` or a `std::array`.  Changing the signature of `foo` is out of the table.  Also, this question applies to C++11 and C++14.

Comment: *foo takes in a collection* It takes a reference to `std::vector`. Are you asking how to make a reference to `std::vector` such that it would reference a part of a larger collection and avoid copying? You cannot. So you either do the copying, or change `foo` to take something other than `const std::vector<int> &`.

Comment: Ah sorry, that was not clear from your question. In that case you will have to live with the copy. You could recycle the `v_slice` vector to avoid reallocations but that's about it I guess.

Comment: Oh and the third-party library should be getting a bug report. Accepting a `vector` argument where a pair of iterators would do is a bug.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I'm sorry but a function taking in a `std::vector` as an input parameter is not a bug. At most, it would justify a feature request.

Comment: @RAM It is sub optimal design for sure if the vector is only being read and not sunk.

Comment: I changed code to avoid UB shown, but It seems I had bad copy pasted, fixed now.

Comment: I would reject such a function in a code review. It costs nothing to do it right, so please do it right. You may call it whatever you want.

Comment: `range-v3` is the prototype for C++20 `<ranges>`. It started arounnd 2013, So it must compile under C++14. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

With `std::transform`, you might have your `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> sliced_n(const std::vector<int>& v, std::size_t n)
{
    if (v.size() < n) throw std::invalid_argument("");

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> res;

    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end() - n + 1,
                   std::back_inserter(res),
                   [n](auto &e){ return std::vector(&e, &e + n); });
    return res;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  auto sliced = sliced_n(v, 3);
  std::vector<int> v_out;
  std::transform(sliced.begin(), sliced.end(),
                 std::back_inserter(v_out),
                 [](const auto& v){ return foo(v); });
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8Yvo9qrfE)

but simpler

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end() + 1 - n,
               std::back_inserter(v_out),
               [&](const auto& e){ return foo(std::vector(&e, &e + n)); });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5nM3TPdEK)

Comment: As mentioned previously, your example is broken as it fails to iterate over `{8,9,10}`.

Comment: Offset fixed...